# How to specify minimum or maximum possible values in a forecast?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

Is there a way to specify minimum or maximum possible values in a forecast done with ETS/ARIMA models?

Such as when forecasting a trend in % that can only go between 0% and 100%.

I am using R package `forecast` (and function `forecast`).

Comment: @ZheyuanLi won't your error estimates be wrong then? This sounds like more of a statistical question

Comment: @ssdecontrol perhaps the error estimates could be capped by a ceiling/floor?

Comment: Not really a StackOverflow Q, but: one option would be to transform your 0-1 data to log odds, run ETS/ARIMA on that time series, and then transform back to 0-1 after modeling and forecasting.

Comment: @Mihael no. You should ask about this on https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: OK, thanks, but what if it is not a 0 to 1 data, but a continuous data that has a natural floor or ceiling, e.g. length that cannot be negative?

Comment: If it's bounded at zero, like a count, then you can just log transform the values (adding 1 first if there are 0s in your series) before modeling, and transform back after. On this topic, see http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/forecasting-within-limits/ and http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/transformations/.

Comment: Thanks, that's a brilliant and pretty comprehensive answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your time series `y` has a natural bound `[a, b]`, you should take a "logit-alike" transform first:

```
f <- function (x, a, b) log((x - a) / (b - x))
yy <- f(y, a, b)
```

Then the resulting `yy` is unbounded on `(-Inf, Inf)`, suitable for Gaussian error assumption. Use `yy` for time series modelling, and take back-transform later on the prediction / forecast:

```
finv <- function (x, a, b) (b * exp(x) + a) / (exp(x) + 1)
y <- finv(yy, a, b)
```

Note, the above transform `f` (hence `finv`) is monotone, so if the 95%-confidence interval for `yy` is `[l, u]`, the corresponding confidence interval for `y` is `[finv(l), finv(u)]`.

---

If your `y` is only bounded on one side, consider "log-alike" transform.

- bounded on `[a, Inf)`, consider `yy <- log(y - a)`;
- bounded on `(-Inf, a]`, consider `yy <- log(a - y)`.

---

Wow, I didn't know Rob Hyndman has a blog. Thanks to [@ulfelder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1708299/ulfelder) for providing it. I added it here to make my answer more solid: [Forecasting within limits](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/forecasting-within-limits/).

This one is more specific, which I have not covered. [What to do when data need a log transform but it can take 0 somewhere](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/transformations/). I would just add a small tolerance, say `yy <- log(y + 1e-7)` to proceed.